# js: removing multiple nodes from DOM without multiple reflows

Tags: javascript, performance

i need to add and remove multiple node from DOM while scrolling. To add nodes i found the solution of documentFragment, which allows me to add multiple node with only one reflow.

But removing a great number of nodes is very costly too, so i'm searching for a faster solution.

Now I remove every child with a Node.removeChild(...), which causes a reflow.

Thanks

Comment: Should you manipulate HTML string instead of DOM? I think it will have only one reflow after manipulating HTML then replace the current HTML

Comment: Problem is that manipulating an HTML string alone will mean that any listeners that may be attached to the elements inside will be corrupted.

Comment: plus changing the innerHTML attr is very costly i think. Its even better to remove large numbers of elements with reflow everytime, then to set innerHTML = ""

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it has better performance but you can remove the parent element, then remove as many child as you want and after you're done, you re-append it. Since the elements on the dom has not changed, this shouldn't cause a reflow.

```js
// just a dumb code to show what I meant

let ol = document.querySelector('ol')
ol.remove()
let arr = [...ol.children] // for not modifying while iterating 
for (let el of arr)
  if (el.innerHTML != "child") el.remove()
document.body.appendChild(ol)
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>way</li>
  <li>too</li>
  <li>many</li>
  <li>child</li>
  <li>to</li>
  <li>remove</li>
</ol>
```